# requestLocationUpdates crashes App

Tags: java, android

As the title says, my app crashes when I want to call requestLocationUpdates.
Right now I just want to outpot a Log-Message when the Location is Updated, to see how fast that happens.

**MainActivity**

```
private TextView textViewCurrentLocation;
LocationManager mLocationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textViewCurrentLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLocation);

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener mlocationListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "onLocationChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        }
    };

    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location
    // updates
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            mlocationListener);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            mlocationListener);
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="at.itpro.locationreader"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Edit:**
I added all of these permissions --> no changes

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Logcat output**

```
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity                 ComponentInfo{at.itpro.locationreader/at.itpro.locationreader.MainActivity}:         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2108)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2133)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4881)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:659)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:690)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:512)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at com.company    .locationreader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5042)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2072)
09-17 12:50:00.518: E/AndroidRuntime(23726):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Pleas post logcat output.

Comment: add    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` in your manifest.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing my search terms I found the answer myself.

As stated here [StackOverflow - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490031/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-provider-network)

Some Devices do not support NETWORK_PROVIDER, so you have to check first if the networkprovider is enabled:

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,   locationListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have forgotten some permissions. Please consider to add these permissions to your `Android Manifest`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I added all of those, still no changes

Answer (score 0):

Add these permissions in your Application manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```